# Pre populate the discount code in checkout/cart

Tags: checkout, cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, checkout-summary

I want to know if we can pre populate the discount code in the checkout/cart page when customer clicks a button from a page.

Aim is when customer clicks a button from a page it should redirect them to checkout/cart with the product in cart (could grab it from the session) but I want to apply a discount code at same time

Is this possible

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself but apparently is a feature of m2.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/527

> - Create a price rule with a specific coupon code
> - Use a URL link in the format:
>
> http://example.com/index.php/checkout/cart/CouponPost/coupon_code/couponcode
>
> - Replace example.com and couponcode in the URL with your values

Although item needs to be in cart. Wasn't sure that meets your requirements.

Comment: Hi @dominic I have read this but not sure would this work or how to even implement

Answer (score 0):

The other answer here points to a Magento issue that was supposedly implemented, but I've never seen it anywhere in the admin, and people are commenting on that github issue much to the same effect.

I actually wrote a (free and open source) module that should do exactly what you need. You can find it here: https://github.com/crankycyclops/DiscountCodeUrl

It's a relatively new project and still needs more testing, but it's working well for me so far. It's been tested against 2.3, but should also work on 2.2 (if it doesn't and you need it to, go ahead and file a Github issue and I'll take a look.)

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest way is to buy this [apply discount extension](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-2-apply-coupon-via-link.html). Once this extension is installed you can simply share the link with your customers by adding valid coupon code as shown below.

The link will have this format: **http://{[siteurl}}/applydiscount/?code={[coupon_code}}&redirect_url={[any_url_of_your_site}}**.

The coupon code will apply automatically to the cart if the condition is met.